# How can I determine the arguments that make the matrix be one, no solution.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

I'm studying for my final and encountered with this problem.

Basically, the question asks that

> Let
>
> $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
> a&0&b&2\\
> a&a&4&4\\
> 0&a&2&b
> \end{array}\right]$$
>
> be the argumented matrix for a linear system. Find for what values of a and b the system has
>
> > a) a unique solution
> >
> > b) a one-parameter solution
> >
> > c) a two-parameter solution
> >
> > d) no solution

I have been asking my friends for hours, but no one understands the question (we are not English native speakers). So, would you please give us some clues or some answers for this question?

Thanks.

Comment: A unique solution would be one where a=(some number), b=(some number) . . . n=(some number). A one-parameter solution is where you take a free variable and assign a parameter to it, such as s or t, and then come to solutions such as a=(some number)t. A two-parameter solution is where you take two free variables and assign a parameter, such as s and t, and form solutions such as a=(some number)t + (some number)s. No solution is when your solution is equal to zero.

Comment: Row-reduce your matrix. From there it is analyzing what you have.

Comment: @badfilms I think it might be a bit confusing that you use $a,\ b,\ \ldots, n$ to represent the unknowns in the system.  Since $a$ and $b$ are parameters in this problem, it would be better to choose new names, like $x$, $y$, $z$ to represent the unknowns.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the Gauss algorithm to obtain the matrix $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a & 0 & b & 2\\
0 & a & 4-b & 2\\
0 & 0 & b-2 & b-2
\end{array}\right].$$
From this is it easy to see that you have a unique solution if and only if  $b\neq 2$ and $a\neq 0$, a one parameter solution if and only if $b=2$ and $a\neq 0$, a two parameter solution if and only if $b=2$ and $a=0$ and no solution if $a=0$ and $b\neq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the given matrix is 3 by 4 and they talk about linear system, they might actually mean the follow equation

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & b\\
a & a & 4\\
0 & a & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y\\ z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 4\\ b
\end{bmatrix},
$$

where the the vector $(x,y,z)$ is the solution to this problem.